# Why do my side branches disappear from origin after I merge them? Why do my local branches not show as merged, even though I merged them on origin?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a created a new repo in gitlab, and created some feature branches, and merged them via a "Merge Request". The merge works correctly I can see the code in the master branch. I checked the checkbox "Delete source branch after merge". After checking the git graph I am not able to understand the output provided by git graph(vs code extension).

My question is why the feature branches (pink) do not have a merged line ("\") back to master.

Here is the graph on my local machine:

[image]

And here is the graph from gitlab:

[image]

It looks the same. It doesn't have the other branches because they don't exist anymore on origin.

Here you can see all of the successful merged requests for these branches:

[image]

I made the merges on origin, and I checked a checkbox labeled "Merge with squash commit" for each merge.

Comment: Missing information: how did you do the merges? (*Did* you do the merges? A "merge request" is a request that someone—some human—come along and do the merges, and then they have to pick a method.) Afterward, as Chris Maes points out, you must run `git fetch` to pick up the merges.

Comment: Yes, a colleague approved, and then I just clicked the merge button.

Comment: Your local git graph seems to contain outdated refs. There is `git fetch` that fetches remote refs and accepts the `-p` flag to prune local refs that does not exist at the remote (anymore).

Comment: GitLab has "squash merges", which would do this sort of thing. They also have true merges. That's why I asked how you did the merge: was it a "squash merge", or a true merge? I haven't used the GitLab interface though and am not sure what you would have to look for / look at to see what it's doing, so I'll stop here.

Comment: yes, there was a checkbox checked "Merge with squash commit"

Comment: @torek thanks I think that is the answer. The graph is render like this because of the squash commits

Comment: Merge with squash commit actually constructs a new commit directly on top of the target branch. The way this new commit is constructed is by taking the commits on your feature branch, squashing them together into one, and then combining that with the state of the target branch, as a normal merge would do. However, since this is not really a merge, but more like "Pretend I did all my work on this feature branch in one sitting directly on top of the target branch", then the feature branch is not connected back to the target branch. You likely want to delete those feature branches.

Answer (score 0):

Directly quoting [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70435227/understand-git-graph#comment124508512_70435227)

> Merge with squash commit actually constructs a new commit directly on
> top of the target branch. The way this new commit is constructed is by
> taking the commits on your feature branch, squashing them together
> into one, and then combining that with the state of the target branch,
> as a normal merge would do.
>
> However, since this is not really a merge, but more like "Pretend I
> did all my work on this feature branch in one sitting directly on top
> of the target branch", then the feature branch is not connected back to the target branch. You likely want to delete those feature branches.

Indeed, this is happening because of the squash of the merge.

This can lead to a simpler Git history that doesn't include lots of little edits, and just has one commit for each feature you merge.

If you don't care about keeping the history from your minor commits on your branches, this is the way to go.

**But if you are still in school, having that more detailed history can be useful to your instructor so they can see how you are working each day and who contributed each tiny piece of code. In that case, don't check the "squash merge" box when you create the commit.**